# how to set the specific row item option(visible, invisible) in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

frist my english skill weak.

description>

this is list view.

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
ㅣㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅣㅢ <-- this is button  , i init set invisible
ㅣㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅣㅢ
ㅣㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅣㅢ
ㅣㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅣㅢ
ㅣㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ ////// <-- i want make visible button
ㅣㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ ////// <-- specific position

I make the custom `ListView`

`ListView` row contains texts, `Button`.

The `Button` is set invisible option in xml file.

then, I want set the visible specific row button.

I tried that and failed

after make `ArrayList` for `ListView`, marking matching position like this

```
    for(i=0; i<arraylist.size(); i++){        
        int t41=Integer.parseInt(arraylist.get(i).getm());
        if(month == t41){
            confirm_replay[i]=true;
            temp55=i;
        } 
     }
```

I can set the textValue. through `adapter.getItem(int position)`.
but i don't know, how to control specific button.
also try add button into adapter. failed..
also search question in google but my eng skill bad. failed

add my code.

> main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="match day(weekend)"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#2d000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp">
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> list.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yoil"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/vsTeam"
           android:textSize="15dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/league"
           android:paddingLeft="10dp"
           android:textSize="15dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/공갈"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button_youtube"
           android:text="다시보기"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:visibility="invisible"/>
   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/m"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yoil"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/vsTeam"
           android:textSize="15dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/league"
           android:paddingLeft="10dp"
           android:textSize="15dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/공갈"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button_youtube"
           android:text="다시보기"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:visibility="invisible"/>
   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</b>
```

> adapter

```
    class MlistViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<MatchInfomation> matchinformationlist = null;
    private ArrayList<MatchInfomation> arraylist;

    public MlistViewAdapter(Context context,
                           List<MatchInfomation> matchinformationlist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.matchinformationlist = matchinformationlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<MatchInfomation>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(matchinformationlist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView m;
        TextView d;
        TextView yoil;
        TextView vsTeam;
        TextView time;
        TextView league;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return matchinformationlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MatchInfomation getItem(int position) {
        return matchinformationlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_match_list, null);


            button_youtube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
                    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
                    intent.putExtra("query", "Android");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.m = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.m);
            holder.d = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.d);
            holder.yoil = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yoil);
            holder.vsTeam = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vsTeam);
            holder.time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.league = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.league);
            view.setTag(holder);


        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.m.setText(matchinformationlist.get(position).getm());
        holder.d.setText(matchinformationlist.get(position).getd());
        holder.yoil.setText(matchinformationlist.get(position).getyoil());
        holder.vsTeam.setText(matchinformationlist.get(position).getvsTeam());
        holder.time.setText(matchinformationlist.get(position).gettime());
        holder.league.setText(matchinformationlist.get(position).getleague());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to adjust a specific row, you can use the `position` parameter in your `getView()` method in `adapter`. For instance;

```
if(position==55){
    holder.m.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: thank you!!! i solve the problem.  before your answer, i very confused but now i know it is very easy and basic.  thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

before setting the values to the view check the condition whatever you want like:-

> if condition is true then set your view visible 
>   else set your view invisible

```
if(true){
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
 button.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
}
```

Comment: thank you!!!. i don't know where put your code. but for Faruk Yazıcı comment i solve!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question.
If i'm right you juste want your button to be invisble for specific row. To do so add the specific line at the end of your `getView` method

```
yourButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

If you want to hide the entire row, the best way will probably be to change your adapter to diplay only row with content.